# List categories and highlight current category archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I need to display buttons for all post categories. When I click on a button, it links to the archive page of that specific category. Is there a way to highlight the current category?

**My code**

```
<div>
    <?php foreach(get_categories($args) as $category) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category); ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a simple `if` or the ternary operator to add a class to the link then, if its category matches the current one …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<?php 

$selected_category = get_queried_object();
$current_category = $selected_category->term_id;

foreach(get_categories($args) as $category) { 

    $selected_class = '';
    if( $category->term_id == $current_category ){
        $selected_class = "selected_a";
    }

    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category); ?>" class="<?php echo $selected_class; ?>" ><?php echo $category->name; ?></a>
    <?php 
} 
?>
```

You can then add background CSS for "selected_a" class. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well.

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
              'orderby' => 'name',
              'order'   => 'ASC'
            ) );
    foreach( $categories as $key=>$category ) :
     $catLink = get_category_link( $category->term_id ); 
     $classactive = ( is_category( $category->name ) ) ? 'active' : '';
    ?>
    <li class="<?=$classactive?>">
        <a href="<?=$catLink?>"><?= $category->name  ?> 
            <span><?= $category->count ?></span>
       </a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```